# UIView won't move programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c

so there must be something simple I am missing because I just can't figure out how to move my UIView

This is what I have so far

my .m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self buttonLayout];
}

-(void)buttonLayout
{
     UIView *theView = [self buttonGroup];
     theView.center=CGPointMake(50, 50);
}
```

My .h file

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *buttonGroup;
```

So this is what I have so far and i just cant seem to get it to move at all
P.S i don't want it animated as i'm getting my layout to move to compensate for different iPhone screen sizes :)

Comment: What's wrong with `self.buttonGroup.center = CGPointMake(50,50);`?

Comment: It doesn't move it, it stays fixed just like the code above

Comment: I didn't expect it to behave differently--just wondered why you were doing it the way you were.

Comment: Are you sure self.buttonGroup is not nil?

Comment: There was no real reason, I should be using your way because its more simple, but the only problem is that both ways are not working more me at the moment :\

Comment: It says that @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *buttonGroup; is linked to the UIView on the xib

Comment: Is autolayout on for this xib? Pretty sure you will have problems doing manually frame manipulations if it is. Turn it off in the right pane and see if that works.

Comment: That works, but then everything else get messed up on the page, is there anyway to fix that?

Comment: If you're going to do it programatically you have to do three things: A) Remove the view from its parent. B) Adjust the center of the view's 'frame' (not the view). And then C) re-add the subview.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not tested this, but it seems like you need to:

A) Remove the view from its parent.

B) Adjust the center of its 'frame', not the view.

C) Re-add the subview.

Like so:

```
UIView *theView = [self buttonGroup];
CGRect theFrame = theView.frame;

[theView removeFromSuperview];

theFrame.origin.x = 50.0;
theFrame.origin.y = 50.0;

theView.frame = theFrame;

[self.view addSubview:theView];
```

This should work *with* autolayout.

Comment: Im getting "Expression not assignable" error with the "theView.frame.origin.x = 50.0;" and the y

Any ideas?

Comment: Fixed the problem, just use "theView.center = CGPointMake(50.0,50.0);" instead

Comment: @DarkN3ss, Oh yes, that's right. Try my new code. You have to work on the frame separately and then set `theView`'s frame to the other one.

Comment: Also there is another problem i have run into, I can no longer click the buttons inside of that UIView as if they have been send to the back or something, do you know how to fix this?

Comment: This means that you apparently have more views in your viewController. You need to change the `[self.view addSubview:theView];` to `[theViewYouWantToAddThisViewTo addSubview:theView];`. (I don't know what that view is, but you should)

Answer (score 5):

As the other poster says, you can't move views around by changing their center or frame when you have auto-layout in effect.

Instead, you have to add a vertical and horizontal constraint that positions the view from the top/left edge, connect an outlet to the constraint, and then change the constant value on the constraint from code.

Comment: Just complementing, you should declare the constraints like this:
`@IBOutlet weak var verticalConstraintTheView: NSLayoutConstraint! 
@IBOutlet weak var horizontalConstraintTheView: NSLayoutConstraint!`

and then set their values liek this:
`verticalConstraintTheView.constant = 50
horizontalConstraintTheView.contant = 50`

and for all this to work, the view must also have Width and Heigth Constrants

Comment: Instead of trying to type in the outlets myself, I create the constraint(s), select them in IB, then control-drag from the constraint into my view controller's .h file. Xcode creates the IBOutlet to the constraint for me and connects the outlet all in one step. Very handy.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know one could connect an outlet to a constraint! :)

Answer (score -1):

I had similar problem , but when i tried to change the origin as suggested in first solution , i got "Expression not assignable" error.

so i solved it with below solution in viewDidLoad().

First save its center in some temp variable , then change the centre and add again to its parent view.

```
CGPoint buttonCenter = self.yourButton.center;
[self.yourButton removeFromSuperview];
buttonCenter.y = buttonCenter.y + 50.0;
self.yourButton.center = buttonCenter;
[self.view addSubview:self.yourButton];
```

Comment: Removing then re-adding the view is pointless, and likely to cause a multitude of problems. If you don't have a strong reference to the button it is likely to get deallocated before you can re-add it (since outlets are usually weak.)